# Terminator initial script

Tags: oh-my-zsh, terminator

I'm current user of terminator & oh-my-zsh. In teminator I tried to set my custom layout with several tabs and initial commands for every tab. I followed instruction as described here https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2015/11/28/terminator-multiple-custom-commands/
Main part there is this script in .zshrc

```
echo $INIT_CMD
if [ ! -z "$INIT_CMD" ]; then
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    setopt shwordsplit
    IFS=';'
    for cmd in $INIT_CMD; do
        print -s "$cmd"  # add to history
        eval $cmd
    done
    unset INIT_CMD
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
fi
```

Everything works fine except commands from initial script are not stored in my zsh history. If I execute commands directly in zsh it works properly as well. My guess is that history file loaded after my command is executed.

Comment: @AmirRachum Why not just use a workaround or so? `echo "$cmd" >> ~/.zsh_history`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've tried your way and it works but it shares `$cmd` among tabs

Comment: Try adding a `fc -R ~/.zsh_history` in your init script and see if it helps

Comment: Also when I test this code on mac with `zsh 5.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)` it works great. Please check what version of `zsh` you are using and see if that is the source of the problem

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added `fc -R ~/.zsh_history` command before that script, but it didn't help me. My zsh version was `5.2` on Ubuntu 17.10 and it doesn't let me upgrade it till I upgraded my Ubuntu to 18.04. Now I have `zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)` which is last stable.  And the problem with shared history still exists. I noticed that my usual history stored in such way: `: 1527666945:0;mc`. Maybe that's my problem

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for **bash**

> append **;bash** to you custom command

Example:
change `redis-server` to `redis-server; bash`

Comment: Your answer helped me, thank you very much! But could you please explain why `; bash` did the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

> The solution for this (**bash**)

```
echo $INIT_CMD
if [ ! -z "$INIT_CMD" ]; then
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    IFS=';'
    for cmd in $INIT_CMD; do
        history -s "$cmd"  # add to history
        eval $cmd
    done
    unset INIT_CMD
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
    # ----------------required to refresh the shell session
    history -a # append history lines from this session 
               # to the history file
    history -r # read the history file and append the 
               # contents to the history list

fi
```

> The solution for this (**zsh**)

```
echo $INIT_CMD
if [ ! -z "$INIT_CMD" ]; then
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    setopt shwordsplit
    IFS=';'
    for cmd in $INIT_CMD; do
        print -S "$cmd"  # add to history
        eval $cmd
    done
    unset INIT_CMD
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
fi
```